# Why am I getting this GRPCProvider UpgradeResourceState terraform error?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Problem: After updating terraform to 1.0.8 from 0.14.4 in hopes of resolving some other problems with GCP Data Catalog tagging for tables, I ran into new errors while attempting to apply terraforms.

```
│ Error: Request cancelled
│ 
│   with module.ds-bigquery.google_bigquery_table.prism_tables_no_partition["co.expenses"],
│   on ds-bigquery/bq-prism-tables.tf line 249, in resource "google_bigquery_table" "prism_tables_no_partition":
│  249: resource "google_bigquery_table" "prism_tables_no_partition" {
│ 
│ The plugin.(*GRPCProvider).UpgradeResourceState request was cancelled.
```

and this trace

```
Stack trace from the terraform-provider-google_v3.61.0_x5 plugin:

panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not map[string]interface {}

goroutine 4466 [running]:
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google.bigQueryTablecheckNameExists(0xc000df9600, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x2d21b78)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google/resource_bigquery_table.go:26 +0x164
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google.jsonCompareWithMapKeyOverride(0x2526520, 0xc000543940, 0x2526520, 0xc000543ae0, 0x2d22688, 0x40c201, 0xc000df9f30, 0x10)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google/resource_bigquery_table.go:47 +0x63f
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google.jsonCompareWithMapKeyOverride(0x275dac0, 0xc000c5ec00, 0x275dac0, 0xc000c5f140, 0x2d22688, 0x1, 0xc000f90120, 0xc000fd1000)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google/resource_bigquery_table.go:87 +0x3db
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google.jsonCompareWithMapKeyOverride(0x275dac0, 0xc000c5ebd0, 0x275dac0, 0xc000c5f110, 0x2d22688, 0xc000df9410, 0x194, 0x2526520)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google/resource_bigquery_table.go:87 +0x3db
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google.jsonCompareWithMapKeyOverride(0x2526520, 0xc0005439a0, 0x2526520, 0xc000543b40, 0x2d22688, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google/resource_bigquery_table.go:56 +0x73f
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google.bigQueryTableSchemaDiffSuppress(0x2bf5c3a, 0x6, 0xc000e2c900, 0x88c, 0xc000e2db00, 0x88a, 0xc0012ee200, 0xc000a17500)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google/resource_bigquery_table.go:147 +0x253
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.schemaMap.diff(0xc000936870, 0x2bf5c3a, 0x6, 0xc000946280, 0xc0005426e0, 0x31f89e0, 0xc0012ee200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.4.4/helper/schema/schema.go:972 +0x37c
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.schemaMap.Diff(0xc000936870, 0x31c7be0, 0xc000f6e380, 0xc00124a0e0, 0xc001264c30, 0xc00071fec0, 0x2bcafa0, 0xc0000b9200, 0x430fe00, 0x2561960, ...)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.4.4/helper/schema/schema.go:522 +0x215
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).SimpleDiff(0xc00093b2c0, 0x31c7be0, 0xc000f6e380, 0xc00124a0e0, 0xc001264c30, 0x2bcafa0, 0xc0000b9200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.4.4/helper/schema/resource.go:446 +0x9f
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*GRPCProviderServer).PlanResourceChange(0xc0000d2960, 0x31c7be0, 0xc000f6e380, 0xc000319540, 0xc000f6e380, 0xc0012ea500, 0x320b3c0)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.4.4/helper/schema/grpc_provider.go:693 +0x792
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/server.(*server).PlanResourceChange(0xc000dad120, 0x31c7be0, 0xc000f6e380, 0xc00124a000, 0xc000dad120, 0xc000e6c480, 0xc000847ba0)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.2.1/tfprotov5/server/server.go:315 +0xac
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5._Provider_PlanResourceChange_Handler(0x2b1ee60, 0xc000dad120, 0x31c7ca0, 0xc000e6c480, 0xc0012ea5a0, 0x0, 0x31c7ca0, 0xc000e6c480, 0xc000ee2000, 0x28b5)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.2.1/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5/tfplugin5_grpc.pb.go:362 +0x217
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc0001bc700, 0x3202040, 0xc000702c00, 0xc000fbc700, 0xc00080c960, 0x42d0ec8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.36.0/server.go:1217 +0x50a
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc0001bc700, 0x3202040, 0xc000702c00, 0xc000fbc700, 0x0)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.36.0/server.go:1540 +0xcfd
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2(0xc000721c40, 0xc0001bc700, 0x3202040, 0xc000702c00, 0xc000fbc700)
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.36.0/server.go:878 +0xa1
created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
    /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.36.0/server.go:876 +0x204

Error: The terraform-provider-google_v3.61.0_x5 plugin crashed!

This is always indicative of a bug within the plugin. It would be immensely
helpful if you could report the crash with the plugin's maintainers so that it
can be fixed. The output above should help diagnose the issue.
```

Things I've tried:

- Searching all over the place for all mentions of this error and coming up with similar unanswered questions.
- Deleted the `.terraform` dir and re-ran `terraform init`.

I am not sure what else to try here.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this problem for me was to run the following command:

`terraform init --upgrade`

That was all. If only I could have found this answer posted somewhere. Well, now it's posted.

Comment: lucky you that it worked. I have the same issue and that also did not help :/

Comment: i heart you friend